# What happens if I have a foreign key constraint on django db model but not put that on mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I want to add a field to **Machine** table

```
link_emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name="machine owner", db_index=True)
```

on a django db model.

On **Machine** table I have added the column as `link_emp_id`. Now we don't
do `python manage.py syncdb` for every deployment. We have to add indexes, foreign key constraints through MySQL. I want to know what happens if I **don't** put my foreign key constraint on MySQL(by doing `alter table Machine add constraint link_emp_id_refs_id foreign key (link_emp_id) REFERENCES Employee ( id );`
    but deploy the code with `link_emp` added. Will it still work or `models.ForeignKey` constraint will validate the constraint on mysql too.
In general I want to know what are the validation django performs for such queries with foreign keys.

Comment: You'll see an `ProgrammingError` exception stating column `link_emp` does not exist whenever Django uses `Machine` table.

Comment: syncdb wouldn't add that anyway, which is why it was deprecated in favour of migrations. I don't understand why you wouldn't use migrations, though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman One reason we might be in a position that FK constraint is missing from mysql is that our Machine table is huge. We had to abort the add foreign key operation because it was taking too much time and would impact transactions.

Comment: @Ev. we have already added link_emp_id as a field in Machine table.

Comment: Queries will work but you will be able to insert invalid rows. If you later decide to add the FK constraint you will need to find and somehow correct such rows first.

Comment: MyISAM doesn't do foreign keys, and it works fine with Django.

Comment: it will work fine and I believe that django will do the check to ensure integrity rather than rely on the backed (good abstractionl